# Show git log for a file from a specific branch

Tags: git, git-merge

I'm resolving some merge conflicts for a file and I'd like to see the evolution of the file on the master branch versus its evolution on my branch. I can't switch branches to look at the log history while I'm resolving the conflict. This how I view the log history typically:

```
git log --color --graph -- <path_to_file>
```

Now I'd like to include the branch as a command line argument like:

```
git log --color --graph --branch master -- <path_to_file>
```

Is something like this possible without having to checkout the branch?

Answer (score 3):

There's a fundamental (albeit tiny) glitch in the question itself, but you can get what you *probably* want very simply:

```
git log --color --graph master -- <path-to-file>
```

The double hyphen `--` here separates the non-file arguments from the file (technically *pathspec*) arguments.  It's not *always* required, but it is never a *bad idea*.

The rest of this answer is optional reading.

## Long: details about the above

I said there's a glitch in the question itself.  Here's why:

> I'd like to see the evolution of the file on the master branch versus its evolution on my branch.

The "evolution of the file", as you put it, happens in *commits* and commits are on *more than one branch at a time*.  Some commits in which the file evolved will be only on `master`; some will be only on the current branch.  Some will be on *both branches*.

A nice way to split things up is to examine only those commits that are *only* on `master`, and only those commits that are *only* on the current branch.  To do that, we would want to use Git's "symmetric difference" operator, spelled with three dots:

```
git log [options] master...HEAD [-- pathspecs]
```

Now, by itself (without `--graph` or some other option) this still has a big problem: you can't tell, here, *which* branch the commit was found on.  Using `--graph` does fix that, but is a bit intrusive.  An alternative is to use `--left-right`.  You might also want to add `--topo-order` (because `--graph` sets `--topo-order` on its own): the `--left-right` option marks each commit, with `<` or `>`, depending on whether it's found via the left side name—`master`, in this case—or the right-side name, here `HEAD`.

So, this ends up being:

```
git log --left-right master...HEAD -- <path-to-file>
```

or:

```
git log --left-right --topo-order master...HEAD -- <path-to-file>
```

Now the `master`-side commits will be marked with `<`, and the `HEAD`/current-branch-side commits will be marked with `>`.

You might still want to add `-m`, if there are any merge commits in the range defined by the three-dot `master...HEAD` syntax.  See below for why.  (You can also drop the name `HEAD` entirely—it will be implied by the three-dot syntax—or use the one-character `@` synonym, if you like.)

#### When `--` is required

When you run a command like:

```
git log zorg
```

Git has a fundamental problem: is `zorg` a *branch or tag name*, or a *file name*?  If it's the former, the output from `git log` will start at the commit identified by the branch or tag name, but if it's the latter, `git log` will start at `HEAD`, and turn on History Simplification and look only for commits that modify the specified file (skipping merge commits unless you add `-m`).

Git decides whether `zorg` is a branch or file name by the simple expedient of testing it as one or both.  If there *is* a file (or many files within some directory) named `zorg` in Git's index right now, `zorg` can be a file name ("pathspec", really).  If there *is* a branch or tag named `zorg`, `zorg` can be the branch or tag name.  If it's *both*, well, bad things happen in some cases and some versions of Git.<sup>1</sup>

If there's no file named `zorg` in Git's index, `git log zorg` tries to use it as a branch name, even if you're looking for the commit that *deleted* the file.  You *must* use `git log -- zorg` to force Git to treat it as a file name (pathspec).

If it's ambiguous, the presence of the `--` ensures that Git treats the name correctly, even if you have an old version of Git (see footnote 1).

---

<sup>1</sup>In particular, with `git checkout` in Git versions predating Git 2.23, Git treats it as a file or directory name, not a branch name.  This invokes the `git checkout` mode that means *destroy any uncommitted work in this file*, which Git cheerfully does.

Comment: Yeah I suppose it is safer that way. I'll edit my question.

Comment: However, the git log command was working fine without the '--'.

Comment: I'm updating the answer now with details :-)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to add more details.

Answer (score 1):

You can observe log history of all branches and their commits calling:

```
gitk --all
```

Comment: Wow, that's pretty nice. However, how do I distinguish between branches? All I see are different colors without any names when I hover over them.

Comment: OK, I can see that if you click individual commits it displays the diff along with which branch its apart of. This is really helpful. Thanks Dušan

Comment: @craig there should be branch names in green boxes, you can checkout with right-clicking. Also, You can compare commits my highlighting one and right-clicking another choosing diff this -> selected.  For more details here is a [link](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitk/) to the gitk documentation

Comment: OK, I see what you mean. I'll review the documentation further. I didn't know about gitk before so thank you for introducing me to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
git log --first-parent -m --patch ...master -- that.file
```

will show you all changes to `that.file` on `master` since it diverged from your checkout, folding in the entirety of any changes brought in by merges (which the header will identify for you so you can easily explore further if you want).